# How to check for multiple keys at once using keyTyped(event e)

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jtextarea, keylistener

I have the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyList
  extends JFrame
  implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener, KeyListener
{
    static MyList mylist = new MyList();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel title = new JLabel("<html><body><h1>To-Do-List</h1></body></html>");
        title.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 80));
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        /*
            title.setOpaque(true);
            title.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        */

        /*
            JTextField newTask = new JTextField();
            newTask.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            newTask.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 40));
        */

        JTextArea newTask_field = new JTextArea(3, 1);
        newTask_field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 80));
        newTask_field.setLineWrap(true);
        newTask_field.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JScrollPane newTask = new JScrollPane(newTask_field);
        newTask.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 80));

        JButton confirm = new JButton("Add");
        confirm.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        confirm.setEnabled(false);

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        //listModel.addElement("");

        JList<String> done = new JList<String>(listModel);
        done.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel2 = new DefaultListModel<>();

        JList<String> notDoneYet = new JList<String>(listModel2);
        notDoneYet.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));

        panel.add(title);
        //panel.add(newTask);
        panel.add(newTask);
        panel.add(mylist.createEmptySpace(new JLabel(), 600, 40));
        panel.add(confirm);
        panel.add(mylist.createEmptySpace(new JLabel(), 600, 0));
        panel.add(done);
        panel.add(mylist.createEmptySpace(new JLabel(), 100, 400));
        panel.add(notDoneYet);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        //-------------------------------//

        newTask.setFocusable(true);
        newTask_field.setFocusable(true);

        if(newTask_field.getText().equals(""))
        {
            //Unused if-statement
        }

        newTask.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
                    {

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });

    }

    //Method createEmptySpace(JLabel(), int, int) which works.
}
```

Now I want it to run the keyTyped event everytime I press a key which prints a character (a-z, 1-9, 0, special signs like *, +, # and so on). (Also, I would like to check if the JTextArea is empty after I pressed Enter, Backspace or Delete). The problem is, doing a regular if-else or switch-case-statement is ridiculous. Imagine doing 26+10+dontKnowHowMuch conditions to check every single key like this. Is there a way to make it short so I don't need to stretch it like that?

---

Update: I wrote the following code into the KeyListener:

```
newTask_field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
            {
                confirm.setEnabled(true);
                newTask_field.setText(newTask_field.getText() + e.getKeyCode());
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ALPHANUMERIC)
            {
                System.out.println("Alphanumeric sign");
                confirm.setEnabled(true);
                newTask_field.setText(newTask_field.getText() + e.getKeyChar());
            }
            if(e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED)
            {
                System.out.println("Undefined");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE ||
               e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE     ||
               e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER      ||
               e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE      ||
               e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB        ||
               e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CIRCUMFLEX ||
               e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DEAD_ACUTE ||
               e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DEAD_GRAVE)
            {
                if (newTask_field.getText().isBlank())
                {
                    confirm.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED)
            {
                System.out.println("Undefined");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

And no matter what I typed in the JTextArea and no matter whether the KeyListener is for newTask or for newTask_field, nothing ever happens. The signs appear in the JTextArea, but the KeyListener does nothing. Any ideas why?

Comment: if you just want to get the input character, you can do e.getText(). If you need to test every character, then I'd say the most neat way is to do switch()/case:

Comment: Where do I need to write e.getText()? According to Eclipse, getText() doesn't even exist for e in this KeyListener.

Comment: Was thinking javaFX, sorry. You can call e.getKeyChar() as suggested by MDH. It will give you the String value of the pressed key

Answer (score 0):

Quickly taking a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html reveals the 'getKeyChar()'-Method(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar()), which returns the character of the pressed key.

So you can then use:

```
newTask_field.setText(newTas_field.getText() + e.getKeyChar());
```

As for <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>, there you just check, if you pressed those and do your actions.

So therefore your keyTyped-Body could/should look like this:

```
if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.ENTER || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.BACK_SPACE || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.DELETE) && newTask_field.getText().Equals("")) {
    //do your stuff
    return;
}
newTask_field.setText(newTas_field.getText() + e.getKeyChar());
```

---

After testing the code myself a bit I found the problem, that you add the listener to newTask. After I added the listener to newTask_field instead of newTask, it worked fine.

Out of scope: Maybe create a separate Main-class for the main-Method and have the MyList as a class without a main-Method. Then you create all the objects in the constructor and move on from there.

Comment: Either I don't understand where to use it, or it doesn't help. I don't need a function to print the text in the JTextArea. That's happening by itself when I write there and I don't even need a KeyListener for this. Right now, I want the JButton to be enabled if there is text in the JTextArea and to be disabled if it's empty / blank. The program has to check whether it has content or whether it's empty / emptied and it has to check everytime I press a button because it could change everytime I do so. How does that work?

Comment: Ok, that helps explaining what exactly you want. So with your edited code, what exactly are you doing and what is happening? Also have you tried just implementing the KeyListener-Methods to the class you have, instead of the JTextArea?

Comment: With my updated code, I add a KeyListener either to the JTextArea or to the JScrollpane - both does nothing -  and tried several if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_Something){} statements, without any success. I try adding the A-Z, 1-9, 0 and special sign keys to keyTyped and the noText keys (like Backspace, Enter, Space, Delete, Tab) to keyReleased.

Comment: Edited my answer with a solution, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the info you've provided, it seems that you need something like the PropertyChangeListener().

```
newTask_field.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if(evt.getNewValue().equals("")) {
                
                    confirm.setEnabled(false);
                }else {
                    confirm.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE:**

Or, turns out in order to manipulate the text property changes in `Swing JTextField` you need to use `addDocumentListener()`

```
newTask_field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(newTask_field.getText().isBlank()) {
                    confirm.setEnabled(false);
                }
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                confirm.setEnabled(true);
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                confirm.setEnabled(true);
                
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do I need to edit something to this code? Because no matter whether I add it to keyReleased or keyTyped, or whether I just write the PropertyChangeListener in the main method instead of in the KeyListener, it does nothing.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it fixes your problem

Comment: I had to replace `txt.getText().equals("")` through `newTask_field.getText().isBlank()`, but then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: that is a mistake in the code... I will edit it and fix it

Comment: "UPDATE" does not belong in an answer (that is what [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73797221/revisions) is for). The answer should be as if it was written right now.